# Next available drive letter after C: drive

Tags: batch-file

I am learning batch scripting and need your help please: I have a drive letter string like this (which will vary from each system) - A: B: C: D: E: M: N: P:. I want to capture the drive letter after that comes after C: (Here in this string it is D:). I tried with hardcoded token value as below (which works):

```
FOR /F "tokens=3* delims=:" %%G IN ("A: B: C: D: E: M: N: P:") DO @echo Drive available after C is %%G
```

Can someone please help how to run it for dynamic strings. The letter C: can be at any position. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it with [string manipulation](http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php).  If you're teaching yourself batch scripting, string manipulation is a very useful thing to learn.

```
@echo off
setlocal

:: test string
set "drives=A: B: C: D: E: M: N: P:"

:: strip off everything before and including C:(space)
set "afterC=%drives:*C: =%"

:: Keep the left two characters
set "afterC=%afterC:~0,2%"

echo %afterC%
```

Comment: Thanks Rojo a lot. It was real urgent and working as expected. Cool